# Find all the actors that made more movies with Yash Chopra than any other director

Tags: sql

[Scehma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mr4u.jpg)

```
    SELECT   p1.pid, 
         p1.NAME, 
         Count(movie.mid) AS movieswithyc 
FROM     person           AS p1 natural 
JOIN     m_cast natural 
JOIN     movie 
JOIN     m_director 
ON       ( 
                  movie.mid = m_director.mid) 
JOIN     person AS p2 
ON       ( 
                  m_director.pid = p2.pid) 
WHERE    p2.NAME LIKE 'Yash Chopra' 
GROUP BY p1.pid 
HAVING   Count(movie.mid) >ALL 
         ( 
                    SELECT     Count(movie.mid) 
                    FROM       person AS p3 natural 
                    JOIN       m_cast 
                    INNER JOIN movie 
                    JOIN       m_director 
                    ON         ( 
                                          movie.mid = m_director.mid) 
                    JOIN       person AS p4 
                    ON         ( 
                                          m_director.pid = p4.pid) 
                    where      p1.pid = p3.pid 
                    AND        p4.NAME NOT LIKE 'Yash Chopra' 
                    GROUP BY   p4.pid) 
ORDER BY movieswithyc DESC;
```

**I'm not getting the right output. I'm getting zero rows . Can someone modify above query and give me the right output, I have tried various queries but not getting anything**

Comment: **This one is also not working**

Comment: Can explain clearly, what you are trying to achieve. Or probably post your data and expected result

Comment: I'm using sqlite , and I'm getting zero rows after that query.

Comment: Can you clearly show the data of the tables and the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
SELECT first.actor, 
       first.count 
FROM   (SELECT Trim(actor) AS Actor, 
               Count(*)    AS COUNT 
        FROM   m_cast mc 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT m.mid 
                           FROM   movie m) AS m 
                       ON m.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT md.pid, 
                                  md.mid 
                           FROM   m_director md) AS md 
                       ON md.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                  p.NAME AS actor 
                           FROM   person p) AS pactor 
                       ON pactor.pid = Trim(mc.pid) 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                  p.NAME AS director 
                           FROM   person p) AS pdirector 
                       ON pdirector.pid = Trim(md.pid) 
        WHERE  director LIKE '%Yash Chopra%' 
        GROUP  BY Trim(actor)) first 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT actor, 
                         Max(count) AS COUNT 
                  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Trim(actor) AS Actor, 
                                          Count(*)    AS COUNT 
                          FROM   m_cast mc 
                                 INNER JOIN (SELECT m.mid 
                                             FROM   movie m) AS m 
                                         ON m.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
                                 INNER JOIN (SELECT md.pid, 
                                                    md.mid 
                                             FROM   m_director md) AS md 
                                         ON md.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
                                 INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                                    p.NAME AS actor 
                                             FROM   person p) AS pactor 
                                         ON pactor.pid = Trim(mc.pid) 
                                 INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                                    p.NAME AS director 
                                             FROM   person p) AS pdirector 
                                         ON pdirector.pid = Trim(md.pid) 
                          WHERE  director NOT LIKE '%Yash Chopra%' 
                          GROUP  BY Trim(actor), 
                                    director) 
                  GROUP  BY actor) second 
              ON first.actor = second.actor 
WHERE  first.count >= second.count 
        OR second.actor IS NULL 
ORDER  BY first.count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below SQL.

Explanation - First inline view returns list of people with count of their movies with 'Yash Chopra'. Second inline view returns list of people with count of their movies with other directors. At the end, I filter list of those people where count of movies with 'Yash Chopra' is greater than 'other directors'.

```
(select pc.name, count(distinct m.mid) count_movie
from movie m
join m_cast mc on m.mid = mc.mid
join m_director md on m.mid = md.mid
join person pc on mc.pid = pc.pid
join person pd on md.pid = pd.pid
where pd.name = 'YASH CHOPRA'
group by pc.name) lst_yc
join
(select pc.name, count(m.mid) count_movie
from movie m 
join m_cast mc on m.mid = mc.mid
join m_director md on m.mid = md.mid
join person pc on mc.pid = pc.pid
join person pd on md.pid = pd.pid
where pd.name != 'YASH CHOPRA'
group by pc.name) lst_wo
on lst_yc.name = lst_wo.name
where lst_yc.count_movie > lst_wo.count_movie
```

Comment: this answer is in the wrong context. here you comparing Yash Chopra with the sum of other director. which is not a question context.
you are doing like :


`actor1, director1   ->15`
`actor1, director2   ->8`
`actor1, director3   ->9`

let's assume director 1 is Yash Chopra so, as per the question context answer is:
`actor1, director1   ->15`
because it is the highest with Yash Chopra
but as per your query, it will compare like 15 > 8+9 which is not true so it will return an empty set which is wrong as per the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * 
FROM   ( 
                SELECT   pc.NAME, 
                         Count(DISTINCT Trim(m.mid)) count_movie 
                FROM     movie m 
                JOIN     m_cast mc 
                ON       Trim(m.mid) = Trim(mc.mid) 
                JOIN     m_director md 
                ON       Trim(m.mid) = Trim(md.mid) 
                JOIN     person pc 
                ON       Trim(mc.pid) = Trim(pc.pid) 
                JOIN     person pd 
                ON       trim(md.pid )= Trim(pd.pid) where pd.NAME = 'Yash Chopra' GROUP BY pc.NAME) lst_yc
                JOIN 
                         ( 
                                  SELECT   pc.NAME, 
                                           count(trim(m.mid)) count_movie 
                                  FROM     movie m 
                                  JOIN     m_cast mc 
                                  ON       trim(m.mid) = trim(mc.mid ) 
                                  JOIN     m_director md 
                                  ON       trim(m.mid) = (md.mid) 
                                  JOIN     person pc 
                                  ON       trim(mc.pid) = trim(pc.pid) 
                                  JOIN     person pd 
                                  ON       trim(md.pid) = trim(pd.pid) 
                                  WHERE    pd.NAME != 'Yash Chopra' 
                                  GROUP BY pc.NAME) lst_wo 
                ON       lst_yc.NAME = lst_wo.NAME 
                WHERE    lst_yc.count_movie > lst_wo.count_movie
```

This seems to be the answer as given by Mr. Shantanu.
But Do you know why this is taking time, I ran query 1 hour ago and no reult has produced yet.

Comment: can you please put details like number of records in movie, person and other tables? which database are you using? is it relational or nosql db? Please put as much details as you can in your original question.

Comment: I'm using sqlite , and I'm getting zero rows after that query @ShantanuKher

Answer (score 0):

p2.NAME LIKE 'Yash Chopra' and p1.PID
This is your line from the code.
You should have written it like this TRIM(p2.NAME),TRIM(p1.PID) because the Name and PID from your Movie Table contains spaces and things like that.You should process it correctly else it will return zero rows, keep that thing in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.actor,t.count from ( SELECT actor,count(distinct m.mid) as count
                      FROM   m_cast mc 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT m.mid 
                                         FROM   movie m) AS m 
                                     ON m.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT md.pid, 
                                                md.mid 
                                         FROM   m_director md) AS md 
                                     ON md.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                                p.NAME AS actor 
                                         FROM   person p) AS pactor 
                                     ON pactor.pid = Trim(mc.pid) 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                                p.NAME AS director 
                                         FROM   person p) AS pdirector 
                                     ON pdirector.pid = Trim(md.pid) 
                      WHERE  director   LIKE '%Yash Chopra%' 
                      --and actor like '%Uttam Sodi%'
                      group by actor) as t
                      join( SELECT actor,count(distinct m.mid) as count
                      FROM   m_cast mc 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT m.mid 
                                         FROM   movie m) AS m 
                                     ON m.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT md.pid, 
                                                md.mid 
                                         FROM   m_director md) AS md 
                                     ON md.mid = Trim(mc.mid) 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                                p.NAME AS actor 
                                         FROM   person p) AS pactor 
                                     ON pactor.pid = Trim(mc.pid) 
                             INNER JOIN (SELECT p.pid, 
                                                p.NAME AS director 
                                         FROM   person p) AS pdirector 
                                     ON pdirector.pid = Trim(md.pid) 
                      WHERE  director not  LIKE '%Yash Chopra%' 
                      group by actor) as w
                where t.actor=w.actor and t.count>=w.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey folks who are new to **sql** and trying very hard to solve this question like me, you can find the part of a solution(99%) below, as i don't want to interupt your process of learning. But before going through it, try for one last time. I am thankful to the people who have discussed their various thoughts on this question in this forum, as they have triggered various ideas in me.

Before going through the solution you can have a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/QFj-hZi8MKk) to get an overview on various new keywords used in the below code.
disclaimer - use trim option wherever required

```
select actor,movies from 
    
( select mc.pid as actor,
         md.pid as director,
         p.pid,
         count(*) as movies,
         rank() over (partition by mc.pid order by count(*) desc) as rn,
         p.name
  from m_director as md 
  join
  m_cast as mc on md.mid=mc.mid
  left join
  person as p on md.pid=p.pid and name = 'Yash Chopra'
  group by mc.pid,md.pid
 )
    
where rn =1 and director like "nm0007181" ;
```

exact solution - in order to get the exact solution you can join the above **table** with **people** table to get the **names of actors** who had been directed more  by **yash chopra** than any other director.

**paila saisravan - data digger**

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.name,h.count 
from(select mc.pid as mcpid,md.pid as mdpid,count(mc.MID) as count   
from m_cast as mc
                 join m_director md 
                     on md.MID=mc.MID               
                 group by mc.pid ,md.pid 
                ) h
            join person p 
                on h.mcpid=p.pid
            where h.count = (select count(*) as count   
                             from m_cast as mc
                             join m_director md 
                                 on md.mid=mc.mid
                             where mc.pid=h.mcpid 
                             group by mc.pid,md.pid 
                             order by count(*) desc
                             limit 1)
            and h.mdpid = (select pid 
                           from person 
                           where name like '%Yash Chopra%'
                          )
            order by h.count desc
```